# psycopg2 - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rollback'

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to delete records from a postgresql table using psycopg2 from pyspark code. But I am getting error. Not sure what is wrong. Thanks in advance

```
def delete_records(table,city_list,key):
    connection = None
    try: 
        connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host,
                                             database=db,
                                             user=user,
                                             password=password)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        delete_query = "Delete from " +table+ " where "+key+" in "+ str(tuple(city_list))
        cursor.execute(delete_query)
        connection.commit()
        logger.debug("Record deleted successfully")
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
        logger.error("%s transction error Reverting all other operations of a transction ", error)
        connection.rollback()
    finally:
        if connection is not None:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            logger.debug("PostgreSQL connection is closed")

delete_records(table_name,city_list,"id")
```

Error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rollback
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your connection is None. You have checked the None in the `finally` statement and then why not for `except` statement?

Comment: SO it means query is not being executed? and it is going to except block? So shall I add if connection is not None: in except block also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an error is probably happening in the first line of your try, so the connection is still None by the time you get to the except.

Like you mention in the comments, adding `if connection is not None:` to the except block sounds like a good idea.

You probably want to figure out what the logger is saying about the error so that you can troubleshoot, so you may want something like this:

```
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
        logger.error("%s transction error Reverting all other operations of a transction ", error)
        if connection is not None:
            connection.rollback()
```